# Reading UTF-8 Encoded Files and Text Files in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, unicode, utf-8

Ok, so python3 and unicode. I know that all python3 strings are actually unicode strings and all python3 code is stored as utf-8. But how does python3 reads text files? Does it assume that they are encoded in utf-8? Do I need to call decode('utf-8') when reading a text file? What about pandas read_csv() and to_csv()?

Answer (score 9):

Python's [built-in function `open()`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#open) has an optional parameter `encoding`:

> *encoding* is the name of the encoding used to decode or encode the file. This should only be used in text mode. The default encoding is
>   platform dependent (whatever `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns),
>   but any text encoding supported by Python can be used. See the
>   [`codecs` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/codecs.html#module-codecs) for the list of supported encodings.

Analogous parameter could be found in pandas:

- [`pandas.read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html): `encoding`: str, default None. Encoding to use for UTF when reading/writing (ex. `‘utf-8’`).
- [`Series.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.to_csv.html): `encoding`: string, optional. A string representing the encoding to use if the contents are non-ascii, for python versions prior to 3.
- [`DataFrame.to_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html): `encoding`: string, optional. A string representing the encoding to use in the output file, defaults to `‘ascii’` on Python 2 and `‘utf-8’` on Python 3.

Answer (score 0):

> Do I need to call decode('utf-8') when reading a text file?

You need to try-read a text file to make sure it's utf-8 encoding in the file.