# pypy3 - UnicodeDecodeError when reading a csv file

Tags: python, csv, utf-8, pypy

When I run `pypy3 file.py`, I get an `UnicodeDecodeError`, because `file.csv` contains some UTF-8 characters.

However, when I run `python3 file.py`, everything works fine.

The key part of `file.py`:

```
with open("file.csv") as f:
    reader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",", quotechar="\"")
    next(reader)
```

Any ideas which way `pypy3` needs to be tampered with so that it works?

Comment: Likely dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47948518/reading-utf-8-encoded-files-and-text-files-in-python3 - if you specify the encoding when opening the file it shouldn't matter which interpreter you use.

Comment: That's it, `encoding="utf8"` did it! Do you want to write it as the answer?